# html entity/specialcharacters decode

Tags: php, html-entities, html-encode

I have a question about html decode.

I'm using WordPress' gravityforms plugin to manage forms. The formtitle includes the name of the website. 
This week there was a bug in the special characters, the & sign was showing in the mailbox as `&amp;` . I fixed this using html specialcharacters decode which was working great.
Later it appeared that there was a similar bug with the `'` sign. Apparently html_specialcharacersdecode doesn't work with that one so I tried html_entities_decode as well, which also doesn't work for the `'` sign.

Other signs are decoded perfectly such as `< > () : -=+` so I don't really know what the problem is. I just want the `'` to show as `'` and not as `&#039;`.

My code:

```
    function before_email( $email ) {
        $subject = htmlspecialchars_decode($email['subject']);
        $subject = html_entity_decode($subject);
        $email['subject'] = '$subject';
        return $email;  
    }
```

My concrete question is: Is there something I'm missing here? Like maybe some function similar to the ones I've tried or is there something else going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: yes you can use  html_entity_decode($subject);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
$subject = html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES);
```

However, I would advise against HTML encoding before you insert it into the database. Just encode it when you output it. It's better just storing the raw data in the database.

Comment: Thank you !!!! This did the trick. And thanks for the advice. I don't really know how to do that in this case. I don't think it is stored in a database to be honest, just going to the mailserver. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Yes, I will, I wasn't able to do that when you just answered because it was too soon according to stackoverflow ;)